# Android: Fast compare script

Tags: java, android, compare

I need fast script (in Android) which returns missing/outdated files in phone directory. This is my code, but it's pretty slow . It's like loop in loop, that's why it's slow . Any better ideas?

```
public List<String> _GetMissingFiles() 
{ 
    int checked_files = 0; 

    List<String> _Local_Files = getLocalFiles(new File(Config._SDCARD_DIR), null); 
    List<String> _FTP_Files = getFTPfiles(); 
    List<String> _Files_Need = new ArrayList<String>(); 

 try{ 
 for(int i  = 0; i < + _FTP_Files.size(); i++){ 

     boolean found = false; 
     double progress = (Double.valueOf(checked_files) / Double.valueOf(_FTP_Files.size())); 
     String[] _FTP_File_st = strTok(_FTP_Files.get(i), ";"); 
     String _FTP_File = _FTP_File_st[0]; 
     Date _FTP_File_date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(_FTP_File_st[1]); 

     FTP_SyncThread.doProgress("*"+_FTP_File); 
     FTP_SyncThread.doProgress("^"+(_FTP_Files.size() - checked_files)); 
     FTP_SyncThread.doProgress("["+progress); 
     Log.d("FTP","checked: "+checked_files+ " max: "+_FTP_Files.size()); 

     for(int x = 0; x < + _Local_Files.size(); x++){ 

         String[] _Local_File_st = strTok(_Local_Files.get(x), ";"); 
         String _Local_File = _Local_File_st[0]; 
         Date _Local_File_date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(_Local_File_st[1]); 

         if(_FTP_File.equals(_Local_File)) //Found file, now check date 
         { 
             if(_FTP_File_date.compareTo(_Local_File_date) <= 0) 
             { 
                 //DATE OK 
                 found = true; 
                 //Log.i("FTP","[OK]: File Found: "+_FTP_File); 
                 break; 
             } 
         }  
     } 

     checked_files += 1; 

     if(!found) 
     { 
         //Log.w("FTP","[ERR]: File Not Found or outdated: "+_FTP_File); 
         _Files_Need.add(_FTP_File); 
     } 
   } 
  } 
   catch (ParseException e) { 
      Log.e("FTP","Catch error: "+e.getMessage()); 
    } 

  return _Files_Need; 
}
```

Comment: What does `getFTPFiles` do? What happens if you don't read those? Are you doing any reading inside the files? It's a bit hard to read your code with all those `_` infront of methods and variables.
If you're not doing any reads inside the files, you could possible do this reading multithreaded. Split the lists into smaller chunks and read them in different `threads`.

Comment: Have you analyzed the performance with TraceView to figure out which parts are slow?

Comment: I didn't know about TraceView. How to add it?

Comment: @Cœur You've got a lot of work ahead of you...